# Database design for a classroom application using Parse.com

Tags: database-design, parse-platform, nosql

I'm developing a e-learning mobile application where in there are 2 users, student and teacher. The app works like this, a teacher can create a course which consists of different subjects then the students can join a course by specifying a course code. Students are allowed to join multiple courses while teachers are allowed to create multiple courses. I'm having a problem with my app's database design and not sure whether some columns are relation or pointer.  I'm using Parse.com's framework and its database is based on mongoDB, I think.

My current database design is like this:

Classes:

1. Installation
2. Role (not sure if this is needed)
3. User
4. Course
5. Subject

The Course class has these columns:

- code (unique for every row)
- title
- description
- teacher - should this be a relation or pointer to User class?
- subjects - should this be a relation, pointer, or array to Subject class?

The Subject class has these columns:

- Title
- Description
- (Do I need to add a pointer/relation to the Course
  class?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one related object (e.g. a Course only has one Teacher) then use a Pointer.

If you know there will be a limited number of items in a relation (usually less than 100, e.g. Subjects in a Course) then use an Array, it has some extra convenience.

If you think there might be more than 100 items in a relation (e.g. Students in a Subject maybe?) then use a relation or possibly your own join table.

A join table is handy if you need not only the relationship but information about it, e.g.

```
StudentSubject
- student : Pointer<User>
- subject : Pointer<Subject>
- started : Date
- finished : Date
- grade : Number
```

NOTE:

A word of warning though, what if you need to handle multiple teachers for a course? My experience with education says always allow multiple teachers.